# "Trois sous" in the sense of "two-bit"?

Tags: expressions, usage

> C’est sûrement pas avec les misérables **trois sous** que sa femme le laisse mettre de côté chaque mois qu'il aurait pu acheter cette bagnole !

In conversation, I usually use "*trois sous*" to refer to a pittance, a negligible amount of money, just like above. I'm wondering if the expression can, by extension, be used adjectivally in the sense of "***two-bit*** {worthless}", as in "*a two-bit minister*" -- since both "*trois sous*" and "*two-bit*" have a monetary origin.

Can you say, for instance:

> ces **trois sous** ministres

... at the risk of it being misconstrued as "*ces trois sous-ministres*"?

Incidentally, does "*trois sous*" originally come from "***trois*** francs six **sous**"?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the mention of *trois sous*, you then have to say:

> ces ministres à trois sous

This is the standard usage of the preposition *à* used for indicating the value of something:

> J'ai acheté des carottes à 3 euros le kilo.
>
> Prends-moi un paquet à 5 euros.
>
> une paire de chaussures à 100 dollars
>
> la question à 1000 euros

Comment: Ah, so even in its figurative sense, is "trois sous" treated like a numerical value? At any rate, is the form "X à trois sous" commonly used in the sense of "two-bit X"?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I just think *à trois sous* or *à trois francs six sous* sound a bit old-fashioned, a more modern (but less formal) variant would be *à deux balles*.

Comment: You think "trois sous" in my 1st example falls on the  old-fashioned side as well?

Comment: That is open to discussion, but that is how I perceive it. Nowadays, *sou* is mostly used as a simple familiar (almost childish) word for "money" (e.g. "ça coûte beaucoup de sous") or in idioms such as "sans un sou" but has lost the meaning of an actual monetary unit.

Comment: Cette réponse ne vaut pas un kopek... vous vous êtes fatigué pour des clopinettes. 

Just kidding :) I think you should add your comment about `deux balles` in the body of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Au Québec on dirait « [à cinq cennes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_cinq_cennes) », « de pacotille, qui ne vaut pas cher » (Wiktionnaire) : cependant je trouve *des ministres à cinq cennes* plutôt inusité. Je dirais « ces [vaurien](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vaurien)s de ministres », mais c'est surtout la valeur morale, quoiqu'un être humain n'ait pas de valeur monétaire de toutes façons. On pourrait dire « [sans valeur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worthless) » directement, j'opterais pour l'utilité avec « inutile », voire « [insignifiant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/insignifiant) » qui peut signifier *sans valeur*. De manière usuelle à l'oral j'emploierais quelque chose comme « ces insignifiants/inutiles de ministres » ; plus régulièrement avec l'adjectif suivant *ministre(s)*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but I wanted to add those precisions :

**Trois sous** in your first example isn't correct usage. That a man has only **trois sous** means basically that he possesses **three coins**.

The correct usage, as Greg said is **à trois sous**. So you wouldn't translate it as *two-bit* but as *that worth nothing* therefore the phrase **un ministre à trois sous**, as Greg said, can be translated as **A minister  worth peddling little**.

Three coins may seem a lot for something worthless, but **trois sous** actually means **three ancient francs**, which is worth, including inflation, 0.00456€.

Comment: The 1st one was what I came up with as an example myself. While I meant "trois sous" to be taken figuratively, is it interpreted as a specific amount of money: "3 coins"?

Comment: It can be interpreted both literally and figuratively in your first exemple, depending on the general context. If you're writing a story about the France of the 19th Century, it will be interpreted as literally, otherwise, it will be figuratively.

Comment: *Trois sous* does not mean "three ancient francs". The *sou* existed long before *francs* came into use (14th century in France). In its latest use in France (1950's) a *sou* was the twentieth part of an *ancien franc*.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, this is not used (at least in France). In a colloquial way, you could say "ces ministres à deux balles", preserving your monetary reference, but keep in mind that it is indeed really colloquial.